# Is this an unsolvable function composition problem? Or an absurd?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I am solving a PDE problem. In a certain point, I achieve the following equality:

$G(3x+1) = y^2 + e^x$

This is,basically, a problem involving function composition. **How do I find $G(x)$?**

I have faced similar problems needing to find $G(x)$. However, this equality looks like an absurd. I can't see a way to solve this.

Maybe I made a previous mistake before arriving to this line. But I have double checked my previous operations.

Comment: Is $y$ a function of $x$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I am not sure how to handle y in this exercise. It could be an independent variable, a dependent variable (f(x)=y) or an unknown constant. I am treating it as an unknown constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write
$$G(x)=y^2+e^{(x-1)/3}.$$